# xcode base localization not english

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

I'm writing an app, which needs to have Russian language as main and English as additional. So if device is set to any language, except English - it should use Russian localization, and only if device is set to English it should show English.

In my list of localizations I have: Base and English.
Localizable.strings has 2 versions: Base (that's Russian) and English.

Native development region is set to "ru".

The problem is: English localization is never picked up. So when I switch my iphone to English - my app still shows up in Russian.

Comment: Have you tested on a phone (not sim)? Also, often the localization is not properly picked up when testing. Make sure you totally delete the app from the phone, clean the xcode build, switch language and reinstall with a brand new build

Comment: Yep, full reinstall did the job. Thank you!